# WCF Webservice with PHP

Tags: c#, php, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a web service , which method accepts xml data as parameter

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx/MainService.svc?wsdl
```

And for the connection i have a sample code in PHP as

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://xxxx.xxx.xxx/MainService.svc?wsdl');

$xml = '<InternalTransferModel> 
<SendingShopID>15</SendingShopID>  
<SendingChainId>1</SendingChainId>
</InternalTransferModel>';

$retval = $client->GetShopsDetails($xml);

var_dump($retval);
```

But this returns

```
WCF Test object(stdClass)#3 (1) { ["GetShopsDetailsResult"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Why does it return NULL,

Do we have any procedure to debug the WCF service .
And Also some procedures to check where is it going wrong

Comment: Yes, if you have the service running on your local environment. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb157688.aspx).

Comment: Oh no but its not in Local system :( , how can i manage to debug ?

Comment: If its not your service then I'm afraid you wont be able to debug. :(

Comment: Can you give us the wsdl? Or do you know your way around Visual Studio?